# Share directory from Mac with qemu / UTM virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm looking for end-to-end instructions how to share a Mac directory with a virtual machine that's being run with qemu or UTM. I cannot find a `p9` filesystem implementation on the Mac side, so that seems out, and I'm unclear what I can and cannot do with `virtio` on the Mac.

Comment: Set up the virtual machine for bridged networking and the Mac should be able to connect like a physical machine.  I do this routinely between machines including Linux

Comment: Then what filesystem or mount?

Comment: I can get from Linux to Windows with SMB://computer/drive or from Windows to Linux (and so likely Mac) by installing Samba on Linux

Comment: That's the opposite direction of what I want. I want an existing directory on the Mac to also be accessible in the VM, not just the ability to copy files from the Mac to an existing directory in the VM. Presumably I could webdav mount a mac directory, however.

Comment: I don't know for Mac.  I share top level folders and using the methods I suggested, I can access anything on either machine.

Comment: Also this is not a VM or QEMU problem.  Set up in bridged mode (NIC) and then it is just a regular computer folder and permissions issue